# Regex to check the start of String exactly once

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in which I want to match using Regex that either of B1 and B2 occur only once and at start of every new line. Below is the sample and what I tried:

```
public static String testStr = "A1ABC            10.101.0     testString \r\n"+
                               "B100000100111 B18388831993     I am here\r\n";


public static void main(String args[]) {
    String regex = "^(B1{1}|B2{1}).*$";

    boolean isTrue = testStr.matches(regex);
    if (isTrue) {
        System.out.println("TRUE returns ......... ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("FALSE returns ......... ");
    }
}
```

In above case it should return TRUE but if I changed my input to:

```
public static String testStr = "A1ABC            10.101.0     testString \r\n"+
                               "B100000100111 B18388831993     I am here\r\n"+
                               "B2HELLLOWORLD";
```

But in the the above case it should return FALSE as both B1 and B2 are present. I want to check either of B1 and B2 occur only single time at start of line not in between.

I also use the regex:

```
          .*\\r?\\n$^B1{1}.*\\r\\n$ | ^B2{1}.*$
```

Can any one tell me the solution using regex?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This **regex** detects your unwanted situation. Note the use of two flags: `m` (multiline) and `s` (single line - dot matches newline characters):

```
(?ms)^(?:B1|B2).*?^(?:B1|B2)
```

The presence of `?:` suppresses backreferences from being created. (You don't need the backreferences; you only want to know whether you have data that violates your constraint.)

Comment: Hmmm...why the downvote? (And how often does this happen on an excepted answer?!) If my answer needs improvement, I'm certainly receptive to suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to test for the opposite, return `TRUE` if `B1/B2` are present twice, then treat the results as the opposite:

```
(?sm).*^(B1|B2).*?^(B1|B2).*
```

Using multiline flag `(?m)` - [RegExr](http://regexr.com?37gjv)

If you do want `TRUE` to indicate `B1/B2` does NOT appear twice, a little messing around has led me to this:

```
^(?sm)(?!(.*?^(B1|B2)){2}).*
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?37gk2) - Change a line to another `B1/B2` and you'll see it stops matching.

But I'm sure that 2nd regex is much less efficient than just flipping the return value of the first one.

Comment: Noticed that you're using `.matches()` method - which requires the entire string to match. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

for **exactly once** non-matching use this Pattern it will match 0 and 2 or more occurrences of B1/B2 at beginning of lines `(?s)^((?=((^|.*\r?\n)(B1|B2)){2})|^(?!(^|.*\r?\n)(B1|B2))).`

- `^(` beginning
- `(?=((^|.*\r?\n)(B1|B2)){2})` lookahead for B1/B2 "2 occurrences"
- `|` or
- `^(?!(^|.*\r?\n)(B1|B2))` negative lookahead for B1/B2 "0 occurrence"
- `).` grap something to return 1 or 0